# How is closing a terminal window different from killing/exiting?

Tags: bash, background-process

I am trying to help a user at AskUbuntu with the following question,

[Exiting the terminal vs Closing the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368957/exiting-the-terminal-vs-closing-the-terminal)

> **Context:-**
>
> I am running a process in bash with `&` appended i.e in background
> mode. The process has a `while(1)` i.e it will run forever. My bash is
> parent and my process becomes the child. I want to learn how Kernel
> handles the child when parent is terminated.
>
> **Observations:-**
>
> 1. If I exit the terminal (using `exit` command from the terminal), `/lib/systemd/systemd --user` becomes the parent process of the child
> 2. If I kill the terminal process (using `kill`) from another terminal, same result as above
> 3. If I close the terminal using cross icon, child process gets terminated too
>
> **Question:-**
>
> How is closing different from killing/exiting?

I have written an answer, but feel that I do not really understand what is happening, and I think that several of you who help here at Unix & Linux know better than I and can explain what is happening.

So please help us understand, by chipping in and write an answer (replacing my attempt at AskUbuntu).

Answer (score 5):

The answer to 1 is that `systemd --user` adopts the orphan child (i.e. plays the role of pid 1 = init) because it has become a "subreaper" by calling `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1)` before spawning its children. This is a Linux extension.

The answer to 3 is that it depends on the terminal emulator. They don't all work the same.

But generally, the difference between 1,2 and 3 is that in the latter case **bash** will get a `SIGHUP` signal [1] and will resend it to its children, causing the background process to die:

> The  shell [i.e. bash] exits by default upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`.  Before exiting,
> an **interactive** shell  resends  the  `SIGHUP`  to  all  jobs,  running  or
> stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the
> `SIGHUP`.

This is a **bash extension**; not all the shells are resending the `SIGHUP` signal. Specifically, dash (the `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu) does no such thing.

---

But the background process can get a `SIGHUP` signal even in the case of 1, if it has a stopped process in its process group (simulating a terminal emulator with `script`):

```
$ script -q /dev/null -c /bin/bash
$ sh -c 'sleep 1 & kill -STOP $!; echo $$; while sleep 1; do :; done' &
[1] 3317
$ 3317

$ exit
exit
$ ps 3317
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    # 3317 is dead.
```

The *stopped* (not *sleeping*) `sleep` process has taken down its parent process with it. If you leave out the `sleep 1 & kill -STOP $!` part, it will survive.

Unlike the previous one, this is a standard feature of the operating system, not something specific to bash or other shell.

[1] bash will receive a `SIGHUP` signal because it's in the foreground process group, and the terminal emulator has either destroyed the pseudo-terminal (causing the kernel to send the `SIGHUP`) or has itself sent the `SIGHUP` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining case 3. Can you also explain [better] why the background process is *not* stopped in cases 1 and 2, when there is no stopped process. After all, the terminal is closed.

Comment: Thanks again. Your answer and the other one together help me understand :-)

Comment: Please stop removing useful content from the site!

Answer (score 1):

A children must always have a parent (and every process has a parent PID).

In the first two cases, you kill the parent, so your process will have an invalid parent ID. Unix (and Posix) prescribes that `init` will adopt such processes (so the process with PID 1, which now it is often systemd), and such process get a signal (so it know it should adopt the new children, or maybe just kill it). This is also the reason `init` (and so systemd) is important: it can see if important process are killed or orphaned, and it can take actions).

The third case is more interesting. Note: in such case you are not killing the terminal, you are just telling the terminal to exit, so terminal has time to clean up it stuffs.

So now we have other kind of process, controlling groups and job control. Complex topic: the terminal will stop the terminal part (input processing and how to draw characters), but so the terminal (now usually a pasudoterminal, and for sure a pseudo terminal in x) will send `SIGHUP` to such processes, to tell them that the other side hang up. Usually this is equivalent to a kill to all processes in such control group. programs may tell the terminal to ignore the signal, or to handle such signal for a better exit (often a reset of screen). (`nohup` utility may be used to keep the process running also in case of a SIGHUP signal).

So the difference: 1 and 2 kill the parent which cannot sent SIGHUP to children so PID 1 takes care of them (note: and it may kill it, if stdin and stdout are not more available, but this depend on the parenting). In 3 the terminal exit nicely and notify the children that the other side hang-up, so they must handle it smoothly.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now :-)

Comment: `firefox &` and `evince &` continue to work happily after exit from `bash`, but are closed if the terminal window is closed (by pressing the x icon). Is this by intention or just happens to work like that because they have their own GUIs?

Comment: @muru: right. I edited the answer. Thank you

Comment: @sudodus: `&` it is just about process control. The programs remain to the shell process group (which can e.g. bring to foreground with command `fg`. You have two possibilities: you demonize the program (so you request a new control group for your children), or you can try with `nohup firefox &` (possibly you should redirect stdout and stderr e.d. to /dev/null).